# lithium add an external js file to view

Tags: php, html-helper, lithium

in cake we use

$this->html->script('jsfilenamewithdotjs');

to add an external js file to a view
How'd we do that with lithium

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`echo $this->html->script('jquery.js');` returns a `<script />` tag. If the filename is prefixed with `"/"`, the path will be relative to the base path of your application. Otherwise, the path will be relative to your JavaScript path, usually `webroot/js`.

For an external script `$this->html->script('http://foo.com/bar.js');`

Docs: http://li3.me/docs/lithium/template/helper/Html::script()

Comment: If you are running a site that operates on both http and https, you can use `$this->html->script('//foo.com/bar.js');` to have the external script use the same protocol as the page.  You can also use `$this->html->script('//foo.com/bar.js', array('inline' => false);` to not output the script right away.  And then in your layout file, call `echo $this->scripts();` to have all of the scripts echoed out that you've queued up by setting `'inline'` to `false`.  There are some notes about this in the Views section of the manual - http://lithify.me/docs/manual/handling-http-requests/views.wiki